# Is the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7 compatible with .Net Core 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am getting the following warning in my .NET Core 2.2 application:

```
Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7' was restored using 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework 
'.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'. 
This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Are there any alternatives for this package?

Comment: No, you added the wrong package. You don't need to add *any* package to an ASP.NET Core project to create a Web API controller. Check [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). The controller architecture has changed in .NET Core and now supports both Web API and MVC controllers derived from the same class, ControllerBase

Comment: How did `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` end up in an ASP.NET Core project anyway?

Comment: I am upgrading a .net 4.5.1 application to .net core 2.2. I was using types like BsonMediaTypeFormatter and BsonReader. I see that Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core has these but unfortunately, that is not supported.

Comment: It's a different architecture, not a matter of something being supported or not. Web API is baked into ASP.NET Core now. Your real question is different though - how to add BSON support to ASP.NET Core? There are many duplicates that show you need to add the [WebAPIContrib.Core](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib.Core) package

Comment: Don't upgrade an existing project, because you'll miss out on much of the new and awesome stuff in .NET Core (e.g. improved csproj file format), as well as potentially having a lot of cruft left over, as well as running into these kinds of issues. Rather make a new Core project, copy all your code into that, then add the missing references as needed.

Answer (score 30):

As said in comments, this is not needed for a `ASP.NET Core project`. Remove it via `NuGet` and you should be good to go.